# How use Masonry autolayout UItableviewCell height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, masonry

I am trying to autoresize table cell with autolayout. But it seems TableView ignores height constraints.

UIImage and UILabel in UITableViewCell:

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.icon = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.icon];
        [self.icon mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(10);
        make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(10);
        make.width.offset(70);
        make.height.offset(70);
//            make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_bottom).with.offset(-10);
        }];
        self.icon.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        self.customText = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.customText.text = @"xx11dragon";
        self.customText.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        self.customText.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.customText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.customText];

        [self.customText mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

            make.top.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(10);
            make.left.equalTo(self.icon.mas_right).with.offset(10);
            make.right.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_right).with.offset(-10);
//            make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_bottom).with.offset(-10);

        }];
```

In UITableViewClass:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    _cell.title.text = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
    _cell.customText.text = [dict objectForKey:@"content"];
    [_cell setNeedsLayout];
    [_cell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [_cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    NSLog(@"%f",size.height);


    return size.height + 1;
}
```

size.height is equal 0.0f

UITableViewCell height equal to UIimage or UIlabel bottom +10px,how to set up bottom?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 you can use this approach.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```